# "LaTeX does not work well for people who have sold their souls"?

Tags: books, learning

I read the above sentence from *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX* (page 4), and couldn't get what it means. My first guess is it says people who have already got used to commercial word-editing software will be too lazy to learn LaTeX, but I can't be sure. I searched the web but got no result. Don't know if here is the appropriate place to ask this question but if it's not then I can hardly find anywhere else that is.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX! That's an unusual and rather interesting question! Yeah, and you can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the exegesis of such a provocative statement (be it taken from a document about LaTeX or not) is on topic on this site. Why don't you ask the author directly?

Comment: Definitely off-topic -Anyway +1 from me:o)

Comment: voting to re-open; this question is fine, especially compared to some of the others that have been 'allowed'

Comment: @cmhughes I disagree. Who, aside from the author himself, can claim to know what he meant by that?

Comment: @Jubobs But surely it just needs a little rewording: is there any technical reason why authoring or compiling LaTeX documents would require the possession of a soul? Or perhaps the question is intended more literally: is there any technical reason why having sold one's soul (whether or not one had since acquired another) would constitute an obstacle to the use of LaTeX? If so, is a workaround available? This second question is more focused since it does not address cases in which one never possesses or mislays one's soul, or in which it is stolen or repossessed.

Comment: @cfr You would still have to specify what "selling one's soul" means... Depending on your interpretation of the question, you may even have to define "soul"! I'm sorry, but this question still screams *primarily opinion-based* and *off-topic* to me. Only the author (or perhaps someone very close to him) could provide a definite answer.